# How to upload to google cloud storage an image using Python, without saving the image on my local disk?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

```py
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service-account-file.json')
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(my_bucket)
blob = bucket.blob(my_blob)
blob.upload_from_string(img)
```

Comment: If you don't store the data on disk, store them in memory! Try memoryFS: https://www.pyfilesystem.org/page/memoryfs/

Answer (score -1):

It depends from where you are uploading the image or in better explanation from where you store the image... if you wan to get the image from specific link from the web you can **scrape** using python module  selinium or scrapy depends from where you do ... if you want upload using code you might more read the documentation and use the api key to upload ..

I see your code you may need to use scrapy instead of javascript ...